# Retina & non-retina device when we move say in the center of the device, some point on left bottom also gets moved

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, retina-display

We have created a grid on texture by directly dividing the texture using gridsize. 
We have divided the texture into 10x10. The goal is to modify the texture image using finger. 
We are facing issues on the non-retina as well as Retina device when we move say 
in the center of the device, some point on left bottom also gets moved. Not sure why this happens.

```
- (id)init 
{
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) 
    {    
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0     swallowsTouches:YES];
        [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

        if ([CocosDistort isRetinaDisplay]) 
            originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1968-hd.PNG"];

        else
            originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_1968.PNG"];

        texture2D = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];

        [self body_init];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)draw 
{
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glColor4ub(224,224,244,200);

    [self body_redraw];

    glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    isFirstTouch=YES;
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

    if ([CocosDistort isRetinaDisplay]) 
    {
        mousex = (location.x * 2);
        mousey = (location.y * 2);
    }
    else
    {
        mousex = location.x ;
        mousey = location.y ;
    }

    firstPoint=location;
    grab = [self body_grab:mousex:mousey];
    return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    isFirstTouch=NO;
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

    mousex1 = 0.0;
    mousey1 = 0.0;

    if ([CocosDistort isRetinaDisplay]) 
    {
        mousex1 =  (location.x * 2) - mousex;
        mousey1 =  (location.y * 2)  - mousey ;
    }
    else
    {
        mousex1 =  location.x  - mousex;
        mousey1 =  location.y  - mousey ;
    }

    if ([CocosDistort isRetinaDisplay]) 
    {
        mousex = (location.x * 2);
        mousey = (location.y * 2);
    }
    else
    {
        mousex = location.x ;
        mousey = location.y ;
    }
    [self body_dynamics:mousex:mousey];
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    grab = -1;
}

- (void)body_dynamics:(int)x:(int)y 
{
    if (mass[grab].x[0] > x && mass[grab].x[1] > y) 
    {
        grab2 = grab - GRID_SIZE_X;
        grab3 = grab2 - 1;
        grab4 = grab  - 1;
    }
    if (mass[grab].x[0] > x && mass[grab].x[1] < y) 
    {
        grab2 = grab - GRID_SIZE_X;
        grab3 = grab2 + 1;
        grab4 = grab  + 1;
    }
    if (mass[grab].x[0] < x && mass[grab].x[1] < y) 
    {
        grab2 = grab + GRID_SIZE_X;
        grab3 = grab2 + 1;
        grab4 = grab  + 1;
    }
    if (mass[grab].x[0] < x && mass[grab].x[0] > y) 
    {
        grab2 = grab + GRID_SIZE_X;
        grab3 = grab2 - 1;
        grab4 = grab  - 1;
    }
    if (grab != -1 && !mass[grab].nail &&!isFirstTouch)
    {
        mass[grab].x[0]  =  mass[grab].x[0] + mousex1;
        mass[grab].x[1]  =  mass[grab].x[1] + mousey1;
        mass[grab].x[2]  = -(CLIP_FAR - CLIP_NEAR)/4.0;

        mass[grab2].x[0] =  mass[grab2].x[0] + mousex1;
        mass[grab2].x[1] =  mass[grab2].x[1] + mousey1;
        mass[grab2].x[2] = -(CLIP_FAR - CLIP_NEAR)/4.0;

        mass[grab3].x[0] =  mass[grab3].x[0] + mousex1;
        mass[grab3].x[1] =  mass[grab3].x[1] + mousey1;
        mass[grab3].x[2] = -(CLIP_FAR - CLIP_NEAR)/4.0;

        mass[grab4].x[0] =  mass[grab4].x[0] + mousex1;
        mass[grab4].x[1] =  mass[grab4].x[1] + mousey1;
        mass[grab4].x[2] = -(CLIP_FAR - CLIP_NEAR)/4.0;
    }
}

- (int)body_grab:(int)x:(int)y 
{
    float dx[2];
    float d;
    float min_d;
    float min_i;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE_X*GRID_SIZE_Y; i++)
    {
        dx[0] = mass[i].x[0] - x;
        dx[1] = mass[i].x[1] - y;
        d = sqrt(dx[0]*dx[0] + dx[1]*dx[1]);
        if (i == 0 || d < min_d)
        {
            min_i = i;
            min_d = d;
        }
    }
        return min_i;
}

- (void)body_redraw 
{
    int k;
    int i, j;
    if(mass == NULL) 
        return;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture2D name]);

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE_X - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE_Y - 1; j++)
        {
            GLfloat vertices[]= {
                mass[k].x[0],mass[k].x[1],mass[k].x[2],
                mass[k + 1].x[0],mass[k + 1].x[1],mass[k + 1].x[2],
                mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].x[0],mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].x[1],
       mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].x[2],
                mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].x[0],mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].x[1],mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].x[2]
            };
            GLfloat tex[]={
                mass[k].t[0], mass[k].t[1],
                mass[k + 1].t[0], mass[k + 1].t[1],
                mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].t[0], mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y + 1].t[1],
                mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].t[0], mass[k + GRID_SIZE_Y].t[1]
            };

            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
            glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex);
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0,4);

            k++;
         }
         k++;
    }
}

- (void)body_init 
{
    GLint width = texture2D.contentSizeInPixels.width;
    GLint height = texture2D.contentSizeInPixels.height;
    int i, j, k;

    if (mass == NULL)
    {
        mass = (MASS *) malloc(sizeof(MASS)*GRID_SIZE_X*GRID_SIZE_Y);
        if (mass == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "body: Can't allocate memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE_X; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE_Y; j++)
        {
            mass[k].nail = (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == GRID_SIZE_X - 1
                            || j == GRID_SIZE_Y - 1);//value is 0/1

            mass[k].x[0] = i/(GRID_SIZE_X - 1.0)*width;
            NSLog(@"mass[%d].x[0]:: %f",k,mass[k].x[0]);

            mass[k].x[1] = j/(GRID_SIZE_Y - 1.0)*height;
            NSLog(@"mass[%d].x[1]:: %f",k,mass[k].x[1]);

            mass[k].x[2] = -(CLIP_FAR - CLIP_NEAR)/4.0;
            NSLog(@"mass[%d].x[2]:: %f",k,mass[k].x[2]);

            mass[k].v[0] = 0.0;
            mass[k].v[1] = 0.0;
            mass[k].v[2] = 0.0;

            mass[k].t[0] = i/(GRID_SIZE_X - 1.0);
            mass[k].t[1] = j/(GRID_SIZE_Y - 1.0);

            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by modifying my touches moved method:

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    isFirstTouch=NO;
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];//[touch locationInView:touch.view];//

    int gridSizeX2 = 20;

    if ((location.x < firstPoint.x + gridSizeX2 && location.y < firstPoint.y + gridSizeX2)
    && (location.x > firstPoint.x - gridSizeX2 && location.y > firstPoint.y - gridSizeX2))
   {
        mousex1 = 0.0;
        mousey1 = 0.0;

        if ([CocosDistort isRetinaDisplay]) 
        {
            mousex1 =  (location.x * 2) - mousex;
            mousey1 =  (location.y * 2)  - mousey ;
            mousex = (location.x * 2);
            mousey = (location.y * 2);
        }
        else
        {
            mousex1 =  location.x  - mousex;
            mousey1 =  location.y  - mousey ;
            mousex = location.x ;
            mousey = location.y ;
        }
        mousex1 = mousex1 > 0 ? 1:-1;
        mousey1 = mousey1 > 0 ? 1:-1;

        [self body_dynamics:mousex:mousey];
    }    
}
```